# Update a scope variable from a directive (angularJS)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive I would like to apply to multiple input elements to change their value.  I've been successful in applying it to the input elements value, but for some reason that is not being reflected in the scope.  I'm kinda new to Angular and apologize if I'm missing some kind of obvious answer.

http://jsfiddle.net/hmko75td/ JS Fiddle

```
<div ng-app="myApp">

  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <select ng-model='Factor'>
      <option value=1>1</option>
      <option value=2>2</option>
      <option value=5>5</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <input convert-input ng-model="myNumber">
    {{myNumber}}
    <br />
    <input convert-input ng-model="myNumber2">
    {{myNumber2}}
    <br />
    <input convert-input ng-model="myNumber3">
    {{myNumber3}}
    <br />
  </div>

</div>
```

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

  app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.myNumber = 1;
      $scope.myNumber2 = 2;
      $scope.myNumber3 = 3;

      $scope.Factor = 1;
    });

   app.directive("convertInput", function () {
        return {
            require: 'ngModel',
            restrict: "A",
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                scope.$watch('Factor', function () {
                    if(scope.Factor){
                        element[0].value = scope.Factor * element[0].value;
                  }
                });
            }
       };
   });
```

This simplified example shows the crux of my problem.  When changing the value of the droplist it correctly updates the element's value on the page, but that does not get translated correctly back into the scope variable.

Any ideas how to either 1) tell the directive which scope variable needs to be updated or 2) force the model to update based on the inputs value?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One constraint I see with your snippet is that you need all uses of your `convert-input` directive to share `Factor`, which exists in an enclosing parent scope.

In such a case, one viable approach would be to use the `attrs` passed into the directive to extract the name of the `ng-model` binding, and then to update the corresponding binding via `scope`.

```
scope[attrs.ngModel] *= scope.Factor;
```

Here's a fork of your JSFiddle demonstrating this:
http://jsfiddle.net/m4hvre2y/

Another approach to having directives update an `ng-model` in a parent scope would be to declare two-way binding (e.g. `scope: { ngModel: '='`), but it isn't applicable in your case due to the constraint I mentioned above. If you did this, the isolated scope means you lose access to `Factor` unless it's specifically passed into the directive.